# Being able to download, not just stream files, from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have Amazon S3 where all of my files are stored. Currently my users can go to a link where they can stream, but not download, audio and video files. How can I set up a link through either Amazon S3 or perhaps Amazon CloudFront that will allow someone to download an MP3 file or something of that nature?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the file's content header to something other than the media type the browser understands. For example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.EXT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

This used to be a big issue if you wanted to have both features (ability to display/view and ability to download) and you used to have to proxy the file download through your EC2 or other annoying ways. Now S3 has it built in:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

> You can override values for a set of response headers using the query
>   parameters listed in the following table. These response header values
>   are only sent on a successful request, that is, when status code 200
>   OK is returned. The set of headers you can override using these
>   parameters is a subset of the headers that Amazon S3 accepts when you
>   create an object. The response headers that you can override for the
>   GET response are Content-Type, Content-Language, Expires,
>   Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, and Content-Encoding. To override
>   these header values in the GET response, you use the request
>   parameters described in the following table. (linke above)